# Bind computed column to GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP.NET 4.0. I checked a couple of links on this forum as well, but didn't find a solution that fits my requirement.

I have a GridView which gets populated using a query in a method. The query is below:

```
SELECT district_name, count(record_id) FROM districts;
```

I have disabled ***Auto Create Columns*** options and manually added two columns, viz: District and Count. It is obvious that the second column, i.e., Count is not in the DataSource as it is a computed result.

Someone suggested me to use #Eval("count") and so I tried:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField=<%#Eval("count") %> />
```

but it is also not working. I tried creating TemplateField, but not failed to make it work.

How to include this count column in the GridView?

Comment: give alias to computed column count(record_id) like 
"SELECT district_name, count(record_id) as Count1 FROM districts;" and use it like Eval("count1")

Comment: Error: Literal content ('<asp:BoundField DataField=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT district_name, count(record_id) FROM districts;

<asp:BoundField DataField=<% #Eval("count") %> />
```

With

```
SELECT district_name, count(record_id) as count FROM districts;

<asp:BoundField DataField="count" />
```

Comment: I used like this: <asp:BoundField DataField=<% #Eval("count") %> /> but it is giving error:  Literal content ('<asp:BoundField DataField=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Comment: Previous one is also working. I am using ORM and a POCO was conflicting. Added a custom column with the name "Count" in the POCO, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had commas between the BoundField attributes like an idiot...